# Resize uploaded images, delete original

Tags: image, resize

is there a way to upload an big images -> resize the big image to a small one -> delete the original images.

I`m not talking about Image Manipulations function, but an direct resize.

Answer (score 1):

Use Channel Images plugin to do that. Excellent plugin. [link](http://www.devdemon.com/channel_images)

Answer (score 1):

Photo Frame is a great utility for this, and has loads of advanced settings so it can work exactly how you need. It's different approach to image editing and manipulation. It has a new Focal Pack that allows clients to define a focal point when uploading a photo, then you (the developer) can crop it in any way you need within the template. You could use `{exp:photo_frame:resize}` tag, or you could even use CE Image.

The great thing about using focal points to crop vs actually cropping, is you can resize this photo is so many ways and shapes, without compromising the shot and center point of the focal. You never know when in the future you want to reuse the same photo, with a 1:3 ratio in addition to a 1:10 with the same exact center point.

Resize Tag Reference

https://objectivehtml.com/photo-frame/documentation/tag/resize

More information on Photo Frame and the Focal Pack.

https://objectivehtml.com/articles/read/photo-frame-1.2